# What is `chattr +x` used for?

Tags: xattr

The `chattr(1)` manpage describes the `x` attribute as:

```
x      The  'x' attribute can be set on a directory or file.  If the attri‐
       bute is set on an existing directory, it will be  inherited  by  all
       files and subdirectories that are subsequently created in the direc‐
       tory.  If an existing directory has contained some files and  subdi‐
       rectories,  modifying  the attribute on the parent directory doesn't
       change the attributes on these files and subdirectories.
```

So this attribute is inherited by newly created files/subdirectories, but other than that, the manpage doesn't specify any effect. What is this attribute used for?

Comment: my man page for chattr says `A file with the 'x' requests the use of direct access (dax) mode, if the kernel  supports  DAX.   This  can  be  overridden  by  the
              'dax=never'  mount  option.   For  more  information  see  the  kernel  documentation for dax: <https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/lat‐
              est/filesystems/dax.html>.`

Comment: Yeah, just discovered that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version of e2fsprogs that comes with Ubuntu Jammy is missing some information in the manpage that's present in the [latest version](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html):

```
 x      A file with the 'x' requests the use of direct access
        (dax) mode, if the kernel supports DAX.  This can be
        overridden by the 'dax=never' mount option.  For more
        information see the kernel documentation for dax:
        <https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/dax.html>.

        If the attribute is set on an existing directory, it will
        be inherited by all files and subdirectories that are
        subsequently created in the directory.  If an existing
        directory has contained some files and subdirectories,
        modifying the attribute on the parent directory doesn't
        change the attributes on these files and subdirectories.
```

This was added in [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=bb0ab2a84bb1094b0dfe44c2ed61e9f9813b1c1b), which was released in 1.46.6, the version after the Ubuntu package.